# Is there a hot key for "go to test" in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, testing, hotkeys

In Netbeans there's "Navigate => go to test" which navigated to a class named currentClassTest if it existed (within the current maven structure).

Anybody know if such exists in eclipse?  Or how to setup a hot key for such?
Sorry I'm somewhat of an eclipse newbie and this one escape google somehow.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you have a better chance of getting a good answer if you tag this with "eclipse" and "hotkey".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[moreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/) offers this, among other features.